# Prove that if $T$ preserves linear independance then $T$ is injective.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to prove a theorem, it states the following:

"Let $V, W$ be vector spaces and $T: V \rightarrow W$ a linear transformation, then $T$ is injective iff $T$ preserves linear independence".

I already proved the first implication, but I'm stuck on the latter. I'm trying to use the fact that a transformation is injective iff $\ker(T) = \{0\}$ to prove injectivity.

I also tried with the idea of proposing a base (by definition linearly independent) and write a vector in the kernel as a combination of the elements of the base. I was told this implicitly assumes finite dimensionality which is not included in the hypothesis.

Am I on the right track? Or do I need stronger theorems to prove this statement given these hypothesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $T$ is not injective, there is a non-null vector $v$ such that $T(v)=0$. So, $\{v\}$ is linearly independent, but $T\bigl(\{v\}\bigr)$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

> Note that, $\{0\}$ is a linearly dependent set as $1\cdot 0=0$.

So if $v\in \text{ker}(T)$ and $v\not=0$, then $\{v\}$ is a linearly independent set but, $\{Tv\}=\{0\}$ is not linearly independent set.